# avoid overwriting excel file and create a new name with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

When I ask pandas to generate the excel file, is there any way for him to see the name already exists and create a new file like "dados_extraidos_1.xlsx"

```
if (imovel):
    df = pd.DataFrame(lista_imoveis, columns=['Bairro/Endereço','Valor Total','Metragem','Qtd Quartos','Vagas','Condomínio','Dados Adicionais','Link'])
    df.to_excel('dados_extraidos.xlsx', index=False)
else:
    print('Erro')
```

Comment: You can use os.path.isfile to check whether a file with the same name exists, then name your new path according to what you desire. You can check : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-isfile-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if that file exists already, and if so append a number to it:
Instead of `df.to_excel('dados_extraidos.xlsx', index=False)` you'll have:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob
... # Your code

if (imovel):
   output_name = Path("dados_extraidos.xlsx")
   i = glob(output_name.stem + "_[0-9]*" + output_name.suffix)
   new_output_name = f"{output_name.stem}_{len(i)}{output_name.suffix}"
   df.to_excel(new_output_name, index=False)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helper function to write a unique file.  `mode='x'` opens for exclusive creation, and fails if the file already exists:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

def write_excel_unique(filename):
    base,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode='x') as file:
                df.to_excel(file, index=False)
        except FileExistsError:
            count += 1
            filename = f'{base}_{count}{ext}'
        else:
            return filename
    
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=['Col1','Col2'])
actual = write_excel_unique('output.xlsx')
print('Wrote',actual)
actual = write_excel_unique('output.xlsx')
print('Wrote',actual)
actual = write_excel_unique('output.xlsx')
print('Wrote',actual)
```

Output:

```
Wrote output.xlsx
Wrote output_1.xlsx
Wrote output_2.xlsx
```